# What is a "desavío"?

Tags: vocabulario, significado

I just* had the following conversation in [our chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-tertulia):
<sub><sub>* For a "several days ago" definition of "just".</sub></sub>

> *— Jejeje, es que lo de "aviarse" no es muy común.
>
>   — Bueno, en mi tierra [Andalucía] sí. Aquí hay tiendas que se llaman "**desavío**" por algo :-D
>
>   — ¿Por qué?
>
>   — Pues porque son un desavío.
>
>   — ... pero ¿qué es un desavío? El concepto de avío lo entiendo, pero ¿desavío?
>
>   — Un desavío es la falta de avío.*

Ok, so let's check the relevant words in the DLE then:

> **[desavío](http://dle.rae.es/?id=CWr99n9)**
>
> 1. m. Acción y efecto de desaviar.
>
>    > **[desaviar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=CWlmCHL)**
>    >
>    > 1. tr. Apartar a alguien, hacerle dejar, o errar, el camino o senda que debe seguir.
>    > 2. tr. Quitar o no dar el avío o prevención que se necesita para algo.
>    >
>    >    > **[avío](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4a5NnJb)**
>    >    >
>    >    > 1. m. Prevención, apresto.
>    >    > 2. m. Entre pastores y gente de campo, provisión que se lleva al hato para alimentarse durante el tiempo que se tarda en volver al pueblo o cortijo.
>    >    > 3. m. Conveniencia, interés o provecho personal. Ir a su avío. Hacer su avío.
>    >    > 4. m. *Bol., El Salv., Méx*. y *Perú*. Préstamo en dinero o efectos, que se hace a los labradores, ganaderos o mineros.
>    >    > 5. m. pl. Utensilios necesarios para algo. Avíos de escribir, de coser, de afeitar.
> 2. m. *And*. Trastorno producido a alguien.

So, on one hand we've got that a "**desavío**" can be defined as "action and effect of taking away something that is necessary or convenient".
On the other hand, and just in Andalucia (according to the DLE), a "**desavío**" would be a "disorder caused to somebody".
And on a third hand, we'd have the meaning of "making someone deviate from the path they should follow", which may not be relevant here, or maybe it is?

Well, maybe I'm a bit dense :D but I still cannot see why a shop would be called a "desavío". Are the shops causing a disorder? Do they take away what is necessary? How would a shop do that? Are they just distracting?

**What exactly is a "desavío", and what would be some examples of using it like in the above conversation?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Igual en la conversación de aquel día no estuve muy afortunado. Las llaman tiendas de "desavío" porque es adonde vas cuando tienes un desavío. Te pongo un ejemplo: supongamos que quieres hacer una tarta un domingo por la mañana, necesitas huevos y ves que no tienes. La falta de huevos es en sí un *desavío* (falta de avío, de provisiones). Y lo que te ha causado esa falta de huevos es un *desavío* (trastorno) al no poder cumplir tu objetivo de hacer una tarta.

Las tiendas de desavíos son tiendas que suelen estar abiertas en horarios en los que habitualmente todas las demás tiendas están cerradas, como los sábados por la tarde hasta más tarde de lo que suele ser común, los domingos, etc. Por tanto, podrías ir a un *desavío* (tienda para mitigar los *desavíos*) a comprar esos huevos que te faltan.

Comment: @walen de hecho hay también algunas tiendas que se llaman "el avío", pero son las que menos. Por otro lado, en Andalucía también se puede decir "aviar a alguien" con el sentido de "canear" o "darle su merecido". Tal vez eso haya influenciado para que las tiendas se llamen "desavío".

Comment: Muy interesante. Aquí las llamamos **el desvare**